# i have two tables 1st table have some data another table 2nd have all data now join query null value showing in json response

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter

i have two tables 1st  table have some data another table 2nd have all data now left join query put showing in json response null value how to replace null value i am using postman, i am fresher in json field.

if data is present then data show in response like that these fileds

> "athlete_attendance_id":"48","coach_id":"302","athlete_id":"380","athlete_attendance":"1"

```
{"responseCode":200,"responseMessage":"Athlete details Successfully display","data":[{"user_id":"380","athlete_attendance_id":"48","coach_id":"302","athlete_id":"380","athlete_attendance":"1"}]}
```

if data is not present in table 1st
then null value replace with '0' values show in response of postman

> "athlete_attendance_id":"null","coach_id":"null","athlete_id":"null","athlete_attendance":"null"

```
{
    "responseCode": 200,
    "responseMessage": "Athlete details Successfully display",
    "data": [
        {
            "user_id": "377",
            "athlete_attendance_id": null,
            "coach_id": null,
            "athlete_id": null,
            "athlete_attendance": null
        }
]
}
```

i want value in response like that

```
{
        "responseCode": 200,
        "responseMessage": "Athlete details Successfully display",
        "data": [
            {
                "user_id": "377",
                "athlete_attendance_id": 0,
                "coach_id": 0,
                "athlete_id": 0,
                "athlete_attendance": 0
            }
    ]
    }
```

this is model

```
            public function showAthleteData($team_id2,$coach_id2){
 $this->db->select('user.*,team.team_id,teams_athlete.team_id,dev_athlete_attendance.*');
          $table = array('user');
          $this->db->from($table);
                 $this->db->join('teams_athlete', 'user.user_id=teams_athlete.user_id');
                $this->db->join('dev_athlete_attendance' ,'dev_athlete_attendance.athlete_id = dev_teams_athlete.user_id','left' );
              $this->db->join('team','team.team_id = teams_athlete.team_id');
                $this->db->where('team.user_id',$coach_id2);

                $result = $this->db->get();
               if($result->num_rows() > 0 ){
                      return $result->result_array();
                                 }else{
                                     return 0;
                                }
 }
```

controller

```
$team_id2= $this->input->post('team_id');
         $coach_id2= $this->input->post('coach_id'); //coach_id

         $userCount['result'] = $userCount1 = $this->Querydata->showAthleteData($team_id2,$coach_id2);
                    if($userCount['result']>0){


                         $data_arr1 = array(
                        "responseCode" =>  $this->res = 200,
                         "responseMessage" =>  $this->login = 'Athlete details Successfully display',
                        "data" =>$userCount['result']);
                       echo json_encode($data_arr1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IFNULL to check your columns is null then set default value to 0

Ex:

```
   select IFNULL(coach_id, '0') AS coach_id,     
    IFNULL(athlete_id, '0') AS athlete_id,     
    IFNULL(athlete_attendance, '0') AS athlete_attendance ....
```

**Edit:**

```
SELECT dev_user.*, IFNULL(team.team_id, 0) as team_id1,
 IFNULL(teams_athlete.team_id, 0) as team_id2,
IFNULL(dev_athlete_attendance.coach_id,0) as coach_id,
IFNULL(dev_athlete_attendance.athlete_id,0) as athlete_id,
IFNULL(dev_athlete_attendance.athlete_attendance,0) as athlete_attendance 
FROM dev_user JOIN dev_teams_athlete ON dev_user.user_id=dev_teams_athlete.user_id 
LEFT JOIN dev_athlete_attendance ON dev_athlete_attendance.athlete_id = dev_teams_athlete.user_id 
JOIN dev_team ON dev_team.team_id = dev_teams_athlete.team_id 
WHERE dev_team.user_id = '301'
```

Comment: Unknown column 'teams_athlete.team_id' in 'field list'

SELECT `dev_user`.*, `dev_team`.`team_id`, IFNULL(teams_athlete.team_id, 0) as team_id, `dev_athlete_attendance`.* FROM `dev_user` JOIN `dev_teams_athlete` ON `dev_user`.`user_id`=`dev_teams_athlete`.`user_id` LEFT JOIN `dev_athlete_attendance` ON `dev_athlete_attendance`.`athlete_id` = `dev_teams_athlete`.`user_id` JOIN `dev_team` ON `dev_team`.`team_id` = `dev_teams_athlete`.`team_id` WHERE `dev_team`.`user_id` = '301'

Comment: sir i am getting like that error using IFNULL(teams_athlete.team_id, 0)

Comment: You are didn't define the alias for **dev_teams_athlete** edit your sql
**JOIN dev_teams_athlete as teams_athlete**

Comment: sir, its compulsory for every column to define alias

Comment: Sorry No or just change from **IFNULL(teams_athlete.team_id, 0)** to **IFNULL(dev_teams_athlete.team_id, 0)**

Comment: SELECT `dev_user`.*, IFNULL(team.team_id, 0) as team_id1, IFNULL(teams_athlete.team_id, 0) as team_id2, `dev_athlete_attendance`.* FROM `dev_user` JOIN IFNULL(`dev_teams_athlete`,`0`) as teams_athlete ON `dev_user`.`user_id`=`dev_teams_athlete`.`user_id` LEFT JOIN IFNULL(`dev_athlete_attendance`,0) as athlete_attendance ON `dev_athlete_attendance`.`athlete_id` = `dev_teams_athlete`.`user_id` JOIN IFNULL(`dev_team`,0) as team ON `dev_team`.`team_id` = `dev_teams_athlete`.`team_id` WHERE `dev_team`.`user_id` = '301'

Comment: sir, can you make my query

Comment: $this->db->select('user.*, IFNULL(teams_athlete.team_id, 0),dev_athlete_attendance.*');                 $this->db->from('user'); 
$this->db->join('dev_teams_athlete','user.user_id = teams_athlete.user_id'); 
$this->db->join('dev_team' , 'IFNULL(dev_teams_athlete.team_id, 0) = dev_team.team_id'); $this->db->join('dev_athlete_attendance' ,'dev_athlete_attendance.athlete_id = dev_teams_athlete.user_id','left' );//$this->db->join('dev_teams_athlete as ta' ,'dev_athlete_attendance.athlete_id = ta.user_id'); $this->db->where('team.user_id',$coach_id2); $this->db->where('team.team_id',$team_id2);